# Using bootstrap and trying to create a container that takes up 100% of the space between bottom of navbar and end of the view

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to build a map view in my react app similar to what you'd see on Zillow.  Here's a screenshot:

[Zillow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdKYr.jpg)

Unfortunately, I'm not sure the best way to handle setting the container to 100% of the view between the available realestate.

Here's the markup (including some other components so you can see how it fits)

```
<Navbar></Navbar>
<SearchByMap>
  <!-- just gonna put the basic html of this component here -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="map-view">
    </div>
    <div class="list-view>
    </div>
  </div>
</SearchByMap>
```

When I set the `container`'s height to 100% it doesn't do anything.  However, given this layout, how can I make sure that it fits nicely and with `overflow: hidden` so that its similar to how Zillow handles its map view?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do this with flexbox by setting the height of the parent to 100% or 100vh, and applying `flex-grow: 1;` to the element you want to grow using all available space.

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0;}

body,html {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

Navbar {
  background: #eee;
}

SearchByMap {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<Navbar>nav</Navbar>
<SearchByMap>
  <!-- just gonna put the basic html of this component here -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="map-view">
    </div>
    <div class="list-view>
    </div>
  </div>
</SearchByMap>
```

Comment: Thanks!  Let me try that What is your opinion of using `top: 50px; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; position: absolute;`?  I was trying this but afraid it could get ugly.  Also is it a good idea to set body height/width like that for a react app because I only need that on a single route.  :)

Comment: The problems with the absolute position are 1) 50px must be the height of the nav? That's a fixed value where, for example, if the nav height changes, you then have to update the CSS. Flexbox is fluid so it just adapts to whatever size the nav and screen are. and 2) absolutely positioning things removes them from the flow of elements on the page. Not necessarily a bad thing, but can be a pain in the butt. I see no advantage of using absolute positioning over flexbox except for browser support. But there are obvious advantages of flexbox, like the things I mentioned.

Comment: @AskskdRieid and you have to set body/html height to be a minimum of 100%/100vh if you want the flex container to extend to the end of the page. It's not necessarily a problem unless it introduces problems based on your UI and the rest of your site's CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `calc` . If your header is 50px in height then set it to `calc(100% - 50px)`

Here's  a snipppet:

```css
.Navbar{
  height:50px;
  width:100%;
  background-color:red;
}
.SearchByMap{
  width:100%;
  background-color:green;
  height:calc(100% - 50px);
}
body,html{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="Navbar"></div>
<div class="SearchByMap">
  <!-- just gonna put the basic html of this component here -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="map-view">
    </div>
    <div class="list-view>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```